# How can I preserve white spaces between tags with Diazo?

Tags: xslt, plone, whitespace, diazo, xdv

I'm creating a simple Diazo theme.

The `rules.xml` is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <theme href="index.html"/>

    <replace css:content="#form-1" css:theme="#form-1" />

</rules>
```

And in a content file, there's the following lines:

```
...
<div id="form-1">
    <form action="...">
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </form>
</div>
....
```

I expected that these lines were replicated exactly in the same way in the output html. However, they became like this:

```
<div id="form-1">
    <form action="...">
        <input type="text" id="name" /><input type="submit" value="ok" /></form>
</div>
```

That is, every time I have an empty html tag, like `<input ... />` or `<br />`, the white space between it and the next tag is removed.

I've tried to modify this behaviour using `<xsl:output>` and `<xsl:preserve-space>` options, without success.

What can I do?

Comment: Why does the whitespace there matter? Can you show us the XSL file?

Comment: The whitespace matter because it effect the rendering of the page on the browser (because these are inline elements). I can't show the XSL file, since Diazo slogan is "We Write XSLT, So You Don't Have To". That is, I don't have access to the XSL file it generates (or I don't know how to do it).

Comment: If it's so important to have white space between output elements, try adding a `&nbsp;` after each `<input>` in your content file. Otherwise, if you don't have access to the XSL, then you can't fix this. Speaking of which, if you don't have access to the XSL, how/where did you specify the `<xsl:output>` or `<xsl:preserve-space>` options you mention? Anyway, perhaps Diazo should change its slogan to "We Write XSLT, So You Don't Have To, But If You Don't Like Ours Then You're Screwed." I don't know Diazo, but are you really sure there's no way to clone a theme and edit it, including its XSLT?

Comment: I would agree with the comment by @torazaburo. You don't want a browser to determine your white space for you. Inline elements should all be on one line and if you do or don't want white space between them then it should be explicitly defined.

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks for your comment. About your points: 1. I can't add a `&nbsp`, because I can't modify the _content_ file, since it's how Diazo work: I can modify _theme_ or _rules_ files, but not should modifty the _content_ file. 2. Through diazo _rules_ file I can insert some XSL instructions (like `<xsl:output>` or `<xsl:preserve-space>`. 3. Diazo slogan: I completely agree. 4. I'm not sure that there's no way to clone a theme and editi it, but, if it's possible, I will probably lose all the Diazo advantages - remember the slogan... :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this same issue.  This is a bug.

Diazo uses lxml, a Python XML library.  lxml uses 2 C libraries, libxml2 and libxslt.  This is most likely a bug in one of these 2 libraries.

Quite possibly it is this bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=642191

The most obvious solution is to add some margin to the inputs in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to editing your css would be to re-introduce the spaces in your rules file.

```xml
<replace css:content="#form-1 input">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." /><xsl:value-of select="'&#32;'"/>
</replace>
```

This is a bit of a hack but works for me.